# Coloring lines in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, line

I have the next dataset.

```
  code2       clinical.pathway variable value
1  6002536 Primary Rehabilitation        1    19
2  6002536 Primary Rehabilitation        2    23
3  6002536 Primary Rehabilitation        3    22
4  6002536 Primary Rehabilitation        4    76
5  6002598 Primary Rehabilitation        1    16
6  6002598 Primary Rehabilitation        2    19
7  6002598 Primary Rehabilitation        3    51
8  6002598 Primary Rehabilitation        4    83
9  6002602           Hand Surgery        1    68
10 6002602           Hand Surgery        2    29
11 6002602           Hand Surgery        3    29
12 6002602           Hand Surgery        4    71
 .....
```

In clinical pathway I have more factors, in this case 4 more.

I am dealing with the next plot considering as repeated measures.

```
   ggplot(data)+
     geom_point(aes(x=variable,y=value,color=clinical.pathway),size=1.5,show.legend = F)+
     facet_wrap(~clinical.pathway)
```

[image]

I would like to join every point with a line of the same colour as the point.
Something like this:

[image]

The code used was the next down. But, I dont know how to deal with the different colors plotted. If I change the parameter color in line I get a diferent result

```
 ggplot(data)+geom_point(aes(x=variable,y=value,color=clinical.pathway),size=1.5,show.legend = 
 F)+
  geom_line(aes(x=variable,y=value,color=code2),show.legend=F)+
  facet_wrap(~clinical.pathway)
```

If I put as color parameter clinical.pathway I get a wrong plot like this:

```
  ggplot(data)+geom_point(aes(x=variable,y=value,color=clinical.pathway),size=1.5,show.legend 
  = 
   F)+
   geom_line(aes(x=variable,y=value,color=clinical.pathway),show.legend=F)+
   facet_wrap(~clinical.pathway)
```

[image]

Some sample data to deal with it is the next one:

```
structure(list(code2 = c("1234567", "6010480", "6011819", "6011122", 
                         "6011250", "6013164", "6014847", "6005343", "6009382", "6004114", 
                         "6013375", "6004627", "6006660", "6011440", "6012721", "6009379", 
                         "6002612", "6006652", "6009384", "6004392", "6010087", "6010592", 
                         "6010056", "6010733", "6009028", "1231234", "6011250", "6006607", 
                         "6002612", "1234567", "6013595", "6008624", "6008624", "6014886", 
                         "6012847", "6010859", "6012437", "6013322", "6011382", "6004755", 
                         "6010758", "6012818", "6014147", "6004334", "6014223", "6012656", 
                         "6004669", "6009028", "6007505", "6011445", "6010106", "6011135", 
                         "6014567", "6010055", "6005026", "6005158", "6014426", "6013595", 
                         "6014148", "6010307"), clinical.pathway = c("Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Spine", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Breding", "Pain Treatment", "Breding", "Breding", 
                                                                     "Breding", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Pain Treatment", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Breding", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Breding", "Breding", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Breding", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Lectures", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Breding", "Breding", "Breding", 
                                                                     "Primary Rehabilitation", "Breding", "Primary Rehabilitation", 
                                                                     "Breding", "Cooking", "Cooking", 
                                                                     "Cooking", "Spine", "Cooking", 
                                                                     "Lectures", "Cooking", "Cooking", 
                                                                     "Cooking", "Cooking", "Pain Treatment", 
                                                                     "Cooking"), variable = c(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                             4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
                                                                                                             1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                                                                                                             1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 1), value = c(9, 20, 49, 41, 31, 
                                                                                                                                                         28, 29, 21, NA, 15, 30, 51, 77, 48, 29, 36, 22, 36, 67, 0, 16, 
                                                                                                                                                         12, 98, 30, 45, 17, 24, 14, 19, 45, 15, 15, 16, 60, 63, 10, 67, 
                                                                                                                                                         22, 27, 30, 43, 23, 24, 67, 20, 38, 0, 53, 39, 28, 70, 17, 56,
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~code2, ~clinical.pathway, ~variable, ~value,
  6002536, "Primary Rehabilitation", 1, 19,
  6002536, "Primary Rehabilitation", 2, 23,
  6002536, "Primary Rehabilitation", 3, 22,
  6002536, "Primary Rehabilitation", 4, 76,
  6002598, "Primary Rehabilitation", 1, 16,
  6002598, "Primary Rehabilitation", 2, 19,
  6002598, "Primary Rehabilitation", 3, 51,
  6002598, "Primary Rehabilitation", 4, 83,
  6002602, "Hand Surgery", 1, 68,
  6002602, "Hand Surgery", 2, 29,
  6002602, "Hand Surgery", 3, 29,
  6002602, "Hand Surgery", 4, 71,
  6002603, "Hand Surgery", 1, 78,
  6002603, "Hand Surgery", 2, 39,
  6002603, "Hand Surgery", 3, 39,
  6002603, "Hand Surgery", 4, 85
) |> 
  mutate(code2 = factor(code2)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, color = clinical.pathway, group = code2))+
  geom_point(size = 1.5) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~clinical.pathway) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: No, I want same colour in every clinical pathway, I mean in every facet a different color.  for example red for hand surgery and blue forprimary rehabilitation.

Comment: Adjusted per above.